# How to sort digits after certain characters (-) in mysql

Tags: mysql

Can sort digits after certain characters in mysql.

[image]

Thank you for help,,

Comment: Explain.  Why does id 7 come after 5?

Comment: Not enough information. First, answer @ysth comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract each of the 3 parts of `id_coba` with the function `substring_index()` and convert each part to a number and then sort:

```
order by
  id_coba + 0,
  substring_index(substring_index(id_coba, '_', -1), '-', 1) + 0,
  substring_index(id_coba, '-', -1) + 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2nMAGwkvTGHKHRku8E98xy/0).
Results:

```
| id  | id_coba  |
| --- | -------- |
| 1   | 1_20-1   |
| 2   | 1_20-8   |
| 3   | 1_20-15  |
| 4   | 1_20-120 |
| 9   | 1_21-8   |
| 10  | 1_21-15  |
| 7   | 2_20-9   |
| 5   | 2_20-23  |
```

Comment: the middle digits are still not in order,,

Comment: See the demo in my edited answer. Your expected results are wrong for ids 5 and 7